# Компьютер внезапно показал пустым hdd при уже загруженном Windows

Tags: windows, hdd, восстановление

Работал на компьютере. Захожу в мой компьютер и тут показывает он,  что один который 1 тб и занят на 90% из 4 установленных у меня жестких дисков пустой. Пробовал тест поверхности  в 2 раз программах все идеально. Просканировал с помощью двух разных программ восстановления файлов на содержимое. Файлы на месте. Но при восстановлении они не живые. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Теперь будете знать, что диски не вечны и нужно делать бэкапы)

Comment: Что такое "при восстановлении они не живые"?